# How do I serialize multiple checkbox field so the form can be submitted correctly?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a list of fonts that I want to submit throught a multiple checkbox select, and I want to show all the selected checkboxes on another page. When I submit my form I'm getting this error :

```
[<Font: Space Mono>, <Font: Fruktur>] is not JSON serializable
```

How can I submit my form  without having this issue ?

**views.py**

```
def step1(request):
    initial={'fn': request.session.get('fn', None), 'checkbox': request.session.get('checkbox', (False,))} #cookies
    form = PersonForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['fn'] = form.cleaned_data['fn']
            request.session['checkbox'] = form.cleaned_data['checkbox'] #probably this line is wrong, how can I serialize it ?
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('step2'))
    return render(request, 'step1.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('%s' % (obj.font_name))

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    checkbox = CustomChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Font.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['fn', 'checkbox']
```

Any suggestion ?

---

Update : Django Traceback

```
TypeError at /multistep/step1/

[<Font: Space Mono>, <Font: Fruktur>] is not JSON serializable

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.01:8000/multistep/step1/
Django Version:     1.8.17
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

[<Font: Space Mono>, <Font: Fruktur>] is not JSON serializable

Exception Location:     C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in default, line 173
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version:     3.4.4
Python Path:    

['C:\\Python34\\projects\\fyzai',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_flickr-0.3.5-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth2-1.9.0.post1-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_taggit_templatetags-0.4.6.dev0-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_taggit-0.20.2-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\bunch-1.0.1-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django_templatetag_sugar-1.0-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\aldryn_newsblog-1.3.0-py3.4.egg',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 21 Dec 2016 00:22:08 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response

                                    response = middleware_method(request, response)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py in process_response

                                            request.session.save()

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py in save

                                session_data=self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py in encode

                            serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py in dumps

                            return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps

                            **kw).encode(obj)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in encode

                            chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode

                            return _iterencode(o, 0)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py in default

                            raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Any suggestion ? yes post a MCVE. include the full stacktrace. What is the class for Font? are you using DRF if not what is the serializer?

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry, I'm a beginner with django, what's the stacktrace and MCVE or DRF ?

Comment: for stacktrace and drf google. for the other http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @e4c5 Updated, I'm not using django Restful Framework, I use a JsonSerializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full stack trace shows that it's the session middleware that's causing this serialization error. And this in turn in cause by the following lines

```
request.session['fn'] = form.cleaned_data['fn']
request.session['checkbox'] = form.cleaned_data['checkbox'] #probably this line is wrong, how can I serialize it ?
```

Again it's not obvious how it could produce this error but looking at your form it shows that there is a font queryset that's being serialized. For that you need to set a special serializer but hooking it into the session would be hard. Instead why not just:

```
checkbox = CustomChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Font.objects.all().values())
```

In which case you have to change `obj.font_name` to obj['font_name']

Comment: it gives me this error instead the other one, 'dict' object has no attribute 'font_name'

Comment: see the update. Why are you saving this stuff in the session anyway?

Comment: tried it, when I submit the form all the checkbox automaticaly check itself and show me this `"['id', 'font_link', 'font_family', 'font_name']" is not a valid value for a primary key.`

Comment: I'm trying to do a simple multistep form where a user can choose between 7 of his favourite fonts. When the customer comes back to step 1, the infos of what he checked should be kept, everything must be kept at the end of submission so it'll be analyzed by another code.

Comment: In that case why don't you just save just the primary key for the font in the session.

Comment: I thought saving it on the cookies, that's why I used sessions

Comment: so save the pk instead of the whole query.

Comment: How can I do it ? (everything should be saved at the last step form)